# How to restrict access to web pages in the explained matter?

Tags: java, servlets, web, servlet-listeners

I have a web application developed in pure JSP and Servlet. Application can be deployed local servers and run. Now we have a requirement where we will get a notification as soon as someone deployed the application in their server. The application will send us the IP address of the machine which the application is deployed.

We wrote a `ServletContextListener` and added the code into it, so it will execute only once in the apps life time.

Now for the above thing, internet connection is must, that is OK. But the issue is the application should not give access to the web pages/ servlets if the notification is not sent to us.

I know this kind of thing can be done in desktop applications, but how to do this in web applications?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html

Comment: @JBNizet: Filter will run more than once. And where to save whether the notification is sent or not?

Comment: The filter will run every time someone tries to access a filtered web page, and will refuse or authorize access to that web page depending on the sending of the notification. You store the notification sent flag in a boolean variable that the filter has access to.

Comment: @JBNizet: You mean a static variable? what about placing it in the filter by it self?

Comment: It doesn't matter much. What is important is that the listener must set this variable, and the filter must read it. You could also use a servlet context attribute, if you prefer.

Comment: @JBNizet: I believe we can avoid listener. We can put the code into filter.